# Hexagonal buttons

Tags: ios, tilemap, spritekit, game-center

I'm trying to create a map of touchable hexagons and the playing area would be like in Catan game. I would like to use Sprite Kit to do the job but is it cabable of doing that?

Process goes like this:

- user touches one of the hexagons and if it is not disabled game show some actions

[Example of clickable area](http://cdn.appstorm.net/iphone.appstorm.net/files/2012/05/catanGame.jpg)

This is turn-based game so I'm using game center to handle that side.

I have already found [very good article](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/) about hexagonal grids. In my game the playing area is fixed (19 hexagons) so is there easy solution to do that with Sprite Kit?

Comment: Informative:  http://gamasutra.com/blogs/HermanTulleken/20140912/225495/20_Fun_Grid_Facts_Hex_Grids.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a sub-class of SKSpriteNode.  Each instance could hold its own texture(image) and possibly the numbers, playerImages, etc as children.

Include `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to handle the touch events.  Make sure that the sub-class includes: `self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Each sprite includes a userData dictionary.  You can use it for custom info for each sprite: playerOwnership? landType? etc.

There are many options here.  I'd suggest creating your own custom init Method.  Here's one I wrote:

```
    -(id)initForPlayer:(NSInteger)forPlayerNumber inScene:(id)theScene xMax:(NSInteger)xMMax  xMin:(NSInteger)xMMin yMax:(NSInteger)yMMax  yMin:(NSInteger)yMMin
{   
    self = [super init];

    - your code here -

    return self;
}
```

as long as your first word of the method is lower case "init", you can add as many Parameters as you need.  Your return type could be SKSprite*.

You can give each instance some Properties that can be changed from the parent, like background image.

I'd create / store these in an array in the parent to be able to access them individually.in the parent

Comment: I created Hexagon class. What is the best way to initialize all those 19 hexagons in main class (GameScene)? How to create an array of SKSpriteNodes?

Comment: I added more info above.  let me know if you need anything else.